# Why two timers starts javascript issue, when timer start & I press some another timer at that time both timers are running

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout

So here I create one contdown web application using HTML, CSS and JS and now I am stuck that how to reset the intervel time out function when click on some another button.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Countdown Timer</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="timer__controls">
      <button data-time="20" value="20" class="timer__button">20 Secs</button>
      <button data-time="300" value="300" class="timer__button">Work 5</button>
      <button data-time="900"  value="900" class="timer__button">Quick 15</button>
      <button data-time="1200" value="1200" class="timer__button">Snack 20</button>
      <button data-time="3600" value="3600" class="timer__button">Lunch Break</button>
      <form name="customForm" id="custom">
        <input  id="customMin" placeholder="Enter Minutes" >
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="display">
      <h1 id="display__time-left">00:00</h1>
      <p id="display__end-time">Be Back At 00.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here in the script.js file as I mantioned , javascript uses the setTimeout feature of javascript to build one countdown web application and now when in a output browser I press Lunch time button it will show the timer for the next 1Hour and than it is stop in 00:00...
as I want if one timer is running and I press some another button or some custom input for taking seconds than at that time both timers are running.
So please provide the solution that what I have to do.
scripts.js

```
let allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".timer__button");
let valueOfTime;
for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
  allButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    valueOfTime = this.value;
    BackAt();
  });
}

setInterval(function () {
  var minutes = Math.floor(valueOfTime / 60);
  var seconds = valueOfTime % 60;
  if (valueOfTime > 0) {
    document.getElementById("display__time-left").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("display__time-left").innerHTML = "00:00"; 
  }
  valueOfTime--;
}, 1000);

document.getElementById("customMin")
  .addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      let inputMin = document.getElementById("customMin").value *60;
      inputBackAt(inputMin);
      setInterval(function () {
        var minutes = Math.floor((inputMin / 60));
        var seconds = inputMin % 60;
        if (inputMin > 0) {
          document.getElementById("display__time-left").innerHTML =
            minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
        inputMin--;
      }, 1000);
    }
  });

function BackAt() {
  var minutes = Math.floor(valueOfTime / 60);
  let currentHours=new Date().getHours();
  let currentMin= new Date().getMinutes();
  let x = currentMin + minutes;
  if (x > 59) {
    let remainingMinutes = x-60;
 document.getElementById('display__end-time').innerHTML= `Be Back At ${currentHours+1} : ${remainingMinutes}`;
  }
  else{
    let remainingMin  =currentMin+minutes;
    document.getElementById('display__end-time').innerHTML= `Be Back At ${currentHours} : ${remainingMin}`;
  }
}

function inputBackAt(inputMin){
  var minutes = Math.floor((inputMin/ 60));
  let currentHours=new Date().getHours();
  let currentMin= new Date().getMinutes();
  let y = currentMin + minutes;
  if (y> 59) {
    let remainingMinutes = y-60;
 document.getElementById('display__end-time').innerHTML= `Be Back At ${currentHours+1} : ${remainingMinutes}`;
  }
  else{
    let remainingMin  =currentMin+minutes;
    document.getElementById('display__end-time').innerHTML= `Be Back At ${currentHours} : ${remainingMin}`;
  }
}
```

when I click on one button and the timer is running , after some time when I press another button to start the new timer at that time both previous and current timer are running.

Answer (score 1):

This defines a Timer class that instantiates an independent timer, then create multiple copies of it.  The time for each timer as well as how long a "tick" can both be supplied as arguments to the constructor.  Each time the timer ticks it can call the optional `updateCallback` to notify you.

The example starts three timers, one for three "minutes" (a minute it actually set to 3 seconds) that ticks every second, one for six "minutes" that ticks every 500 milliseconds and one for 15 "minutes" that ticks every 200 milliseconds.

**Timer (seconds, period, update, reset)**

- seconds: How many seconds the timer should last
- period: How long a "tick" is
- update: [Optional] A callback that is called after every tick
- reset: [Optional] A callback back that will be called when the timer ends (or if `Timer.reset()` is called)

```js
let oneSecond = 500; // this should be 1000, set to 500 for the example
let oneMinute = 3;   // this should be 60, set to 3 for the example

let sessionTime = 3;

function Timer(seconds, period, updateCallback, resetCallback) {
    this.s = seconds;
    this.p = period || oneSecond;
    this.update = updateCallback || Function.prototype; // Use NOOP function as default
    this.callback = resetCallback || Function.prototype; // Use NOOP function as default

    this.reset = function() {
      this.intervalId = clearInterval(this.intervalId)
      this.callback()
    }
    this.start = function() { this.update(this.s); this.intervalId = setInterval(this.timer.bind(this), [ this.p ]) }
    this.timer = function() { if (--this.s <= 0) this.reset(); this.update(this.s) }
}

function setTimeLeft(sec, id) {
  document.getElementById(id || 'time-left').textContent = `${(''+ ~~(sec / oneMinute)).padStart(2, '0')}:${(''+ sec % oneMinute).padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  new Timer(sessionTime * oneMinute, 1000, setTimeLeft, () => console.log('check 1000ms')).start()
  new Timer(6 * oneMinute, 500, (s) => { setTimeLeft(s, 'time-left2')}, () => console.log('check 500ms')).start()
  new Timer(15 * oneMinute, 200, (s) => { setTimeLeft(s, 'time-left3')}, () => console.log('check 200ms')).start()
})
```

```html
<span id='time-left'></span><br />
<span id='time-left2'></span><br />
<span id='time-left3'></span>
```